# How do I save a servicestack session in a method when not calling the method from an MVC context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, servicestack

I've looked at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#saving-outside-a-service

I still don't understand how if I have a class method that I want to call from both MVC controllers and servicestack services I can save the session. Is it possible without passing a service reference?...Below is my use case:

```
    public async Task<User> StoreAsync(User user, CustomUserSession session)
    {
        using (var db = DbFactory.Open())
        {
            await db.SaveAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed;
            session.ProfileImageUrl = user.ProfileImageUrl;
            session.ThumbnailProfileImageUrl = user.ThumbnailProfileImageUrl;

            //Following only works if I am calling the method from an MVC controller
            IHttpRequest httpReq = HttpContext.Current.ToRequest();
            httpReq.SaveSession(session);

            //What if I call this method from a servicestack service, 
            //I don't really want to inject the service as an optional parameter
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to Save a Session you need access to the **current HTTP Request** in order to access the Users [Permanent and Temporary Session Ids](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) Cookies attached to the incoming request.

The Session Wiki shows different ways to [access the current IHttpRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#saving-outside-a-service) outside of a ServiceStack Service:

```
IHttpRequest httpReq = aspCtx.ToRequest(); //HttpContext
IHttpRequest httpReq = aspReq.ToRequest(); //MVC HttpRequestBase
IHttpRequest httpReq = listenerCtx.ToRequest(); //HttpListenerContext

//In ASP.NET hosts via the singleton
IHttpRequest httpReq = HostContext.AppHost.TryGetCurrentRequest();
```

Once you have access to the current `IRequest` you can save your typed session using the `SaveSession()` extension method:

```
httpReq.SaveSession(session);
```

You can only access the current request via the `HttpContext.Current` singleton **within the context of a HTTP Request**, so you need to ensure `HttpContext.Current` is **not null**. It will be null when accessed via a **background thread** which is likely your issue if your **async method** is executed on a background thread when you'd need to instead resolve the `IHttpRequest` from a HTTP Worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I'll try a few times with ConfigureAwait(true); rather than ConfigureAwait(false) and then try just dropping the async for this.

Comment: Yep, was just the configureawait, I would have put that in place first and then not thought of it when passing session in later.